# How can add NA values to date in r?

Tags: r

I have a vector with date, like this:

```
mydates <- as.Date(c("2004-02-10", "2004-02-12", "2004-02-14", "2004-02-16"))
```

and I would like to add NA values to this vector, I have tried this:

```
example <- c(rep(NA,2), as.Date(mydates,format="%Y-%m-%d"), rep(NA,3))
```

but I got this output:

```
NA    NA 12458 12460 12462 12464    NA    NA    NA
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydates <- as.Date(c("2004-02-10", "2004-02-12", "2004-02-14", "2004-02-16"))    
as.Date(c(rep(NA,2), mydates, rep(NA,3)),origin="1970-01-01")


[1] NA       NA       "2004-02-10" "2004-02-12" "2004-02-14" "2004-02-16    NA         NA         NA
```